# Any way to export/import sql server reporting services subscriptions?

Tags: reporting-services, subscriptions

I have not been able to find a way to export/import subscriptions either in the Report Manager or by SQl Server Management Studio.

Anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own stuff using the SSRS web services. The biggest agro with that depends on your security model (double hops, windows Auth, server farms etc).

OR

you could try this app if you are just moving stuff around:

http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62

Comment: Downvoted this answer because it's just a meanwhile broken hyperlink without any explanation.

Comment: Oh wow, a link from an answer added in 2008 is broken. Who would have thought it?

Comment: Anyone and thats the point. Instead of posting the link the Name of the app would possibly been helpful to others.