# Exporting and importing subscriptions to SharePoint-hosted reports that were created in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, moss, subscriptions

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202295/any-way-to-export-import-sql-server-reporting-services-subscriptions) question in related questions which basically asks the same thing.
Is there a way of exporting and importing subscriptions to SharePoint-hosted reports that were created in SQL Server Reporting Services?

Scenario: During report re-deployments, reports are deleted and re-created, and the associated subscriptions are deleted (orphaned?). Is there a way (automated - either by a custom tool or via SharePoint/SSRS APIs) that I can export out the subscriptions before deleting the associated report and import back the subscriptions after the report has been redeployed?

Answer (score -1):

Something to try...

When a SSRS subscription is create a job gets created under SQL Server Agent\Jobs. The job name looks like a guid so it's not easy to tell one subscription from another. But you can right click on the job and the "Script Job as" options are available.

I'm sure someone with more T-SQL could come up with a neat little script that does everything for you. But that would be a whole new question. :)

Note: I know this for sure with SSRS 2005 I would image 2008 is similar.

Comment: thanks, I will give that a try .. how will SharePoint figure out that recreated subscription job bar is tied to report foo?

Comment: I have very limited experience with the SharePoint side of your question. I would imagine though that the job bar is stored in some SQL Server table somewhere. You will probably need a script that does both at the same time. Sorry I can't provide you more than that.

Comment: If I may ask though, why are the reports deleted on re-deployment? Is that a SharePoint "feature"?